# Java applet crashes after closing the java console

Tags: java, applet

I have a java applet that does digital signing of documents. The applet is used in two separate web applications and works fine in both of them.

However following strange thing happens:

When I use the java console for debugging purposes and:

1. I open the applet in System A, sign a document and close (no errors);
2. I close the java console;
3. I try to sign a document with the exact same applet in system B and it throws an exception (NPE, the extracted certificate from the signature is null).

Using the applet only in system B runs normally without any errors and even more: if I repeat the exact same steps described above but without closing the console the whole thing runs as expected without any error.

What could cause such a behavior?

Comment: Does the application work in System B when you don't close the Java console?

Comment: For your signing do you use smart cards (so is some kind of hardware attached) or is everything plain software?

Comment: I indeed use a issued by an verified authority digital signature (which is a certificate installed on an USB drive)

Comment: Ok, then I may be have an idea but need so more information first: Can you have a look how the communication with this device is done? Does it use JNA or jni directly? Or is it a normal "file drive" usb?

Answer (score 1):

Since the notification mechanism seems broken to me, I ask the question here:

***Q: For your signing do you use smart cards (so is some kind of hardware attached) or is everything plain software?***

A: I indeed use a issued by an verified authority digital signature (which is a certificate installed on an USB drive)

***Q: How does the communication with that device work - does it use [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) or [JNI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/index.html) directly? Or is it a normal "file drive" usb?*** (Note you can find out if you e.g. search for jna.jar or jna*.jar)

A:  No I don't use JNA/JNI. I use a normal "file drive" usb. The issue is not critical because most client won't use java console anyways

***Q: Can you put your certificate on your local hard disk or "into" the Applet.jar and load it from there? Does the problem persist?***

A: ?

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply, no I don't use JNA/JNI. I use a normal "file drive" usb. The issue is not critical because most client won't use java console anyways, but I'm really curious what can cause such a behaviour.